# Nullpointer Exception at runtime in Android

Tags: android

I want to write .txt file from raw folder. I add 12 button on activity after click on any one of this its getting NullPointer exception and does not write .txt file from raw folder.

Here is code.

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {

    RadioButton answer1;
    RadioButton answer2;
    RadioButton answer3;
    RadioButton answer4;
    RadioGroup answers;
    int correctAns[];
    Button finish;
    private android.view.View.OnClickListener finishListener;
    Button next;
    Button prev;

    private android.view.View.OnClickListener nextListener;
    int numEvents;

    private android.view.View.OnClickListener prevListener;
    int quesIndex;
    EditText question;
    boolean review;
    int selected[];
    int selectedAnswer;

    public QuestionActivity() {

        question = null;
        answer1 = null;
        answer2 = null;
        answer3 = null;
        answer4 = null;
        answers = null;
        finish = null;
        selectedAnswer = -1;
        quesIndex = 0;
        numEvents = 0;
        selected = null;
        correctAns = null;
        review = false;
        next = null;


        nextListener = new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                setAnswer();
                QuestionActivity questionactivity = QuestionActivity.this;
                questionactivity.quesIndex = 1 + questionactivity.quesIndex;
                if (quesIndex >= ComputerActivity.getQuesList().length())
                {
                    quesIndex = -1 + ComputerActivity.getQuesList().length();
                }
                showQuestion(quesIndex, review);
            }

        };
        prevListener = new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                setAnswer();
                QuestionActivity questionactivity = QuestionActivity.this;
                questionactivity.quesIndex = -1 + questionactivity.quesIndex;
                if (quesIndex < 0)
                {
                    quesIndex = 0;
                }
                showQuestion(quesIndex, review);
            }

        };
    }

    private void setAnswer() {
        if (answer1.isChecked()) {
            selected[quesIndex] = 0;
        }
        if (answer2.isChecked()) {
            selected[quesIndex] = 1;
        }
        if (answer3.isChecked()) {
            selected[quesIndex] = 2;
        }
        if (answer4.isChecked()) {
            selected[quesIndex] = 3;
        }
        Log.d("", Arrays.toString(selected));
        Log.d("", Arrays.toString(correctAns));
    }

    private void setScoreTitle() {
        setTitle((new StringBuilder("Bank GK-I   ")).append(1 + quesIndex)
                .append("/").append(ComputerActivity.getQuesList().length())
                .toString());
    }

    private void showQuestion(int i, boolean flag)
    {
        try 
        {
            JSONObject jsonobject = ComputerActivity.getQuesList().getJSONObject(i);
            String s = jsonobject.getString("Question");

            if (correctAns[i] == -1)
            {
                String s5 = jsonobject.getString("CorrectAnswer");
                correctAns[i] = Integer.parseInt(s5);
            }

            question.setText(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length());
            answers.check(-1);
            answer1.setTextColor(-1);
            answer2.setTextColor(-1);
            answer3.setTextColor(-1);
            answer4.setTextColor(-1);

            JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Answers");
            String s1 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0).getString("Answer");
            answer1.setText(s1.toCharArray(), 0, s1.length());

            String s2 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(1).getString("Answer");
            answer2.setText(s2.toCharArray(), 0, s2.length());

            String s3 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(2).getString("Answer");
            answer3.setText(s3.toCharArray(), 0, s3.length());

            String s4 = jsonarray.getJSONObject(3).getString("Answer");
            answer4.setText(s4.toCharArray(), 0, s4.length());
            Log.d("",(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(selected[i]))).toString());

            if (selected[i] == 0) {
                answers.check(0x7f060013);
            }
            if (selected[i] == 1) {
                answers.check(0x7f060014);
            }
            if (selected[i] == 2) {
                answers.check(0x7f060015);
            }
            if (selected[i] == 3) {
                answers.check(0x7f060016);
            }
            setScoreTitle();
            if (quesIndex == -1 + ComputerActivity.getQuesList().length()) {
                next.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (quesIndex == 0) {
                prev.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (quesIndex > 0) {
                prev.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (quesIndex < -1 + ComputerActivity.getQuesList().length()) {
                next.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e(getClass().toString(), exception.getMessage(),
                    exception.getCause());
            return;
        }
        if (!flag) {

        }
        Log.d("review", (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(selected[i])))
                .append(correctAns[i]).toString());
        if (selected[i] != correctAns[i]) {
            if (selected[i] == 0) {
                answer1.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
            }
            if (selected[i] == 1) {
                answer2.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
            }
            if (selected[i] == 2) {
                answer3.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
            }
            if (selected[i] == 3) {
                answer4.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
            }
        }
        if (correctAns[i] == 0) {
            answer1.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
        }
        if (correctAns[i] == 1) {
            answer2.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
        }
        if (correctAns[i] == 2) {
            answer3.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
        }
        if (correctAns[i] == 3) {
            answer4.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);

                question = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.question);
                answers = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answers);
                answer1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.a0);
                answer2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.a1);
                answer3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.a2);
                answer4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.a3);

                ((Button)findViewById(R.id.finish)).setOnClickListener(finishListener);

                prev = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Prev);
                prev.setOnClickListener(prevListener);

                next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);
                next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);

                selected = new int[GAActivity.getQuesList().length()];
                Arrays.fill(selected, -1);

                correctAns = new int[GAActivity.getQuesList().length()];
                Arrays.fill(correctAns, -1);

                showQuestion(0, review);

    }

}
```

Here is my log cat stack trace

```
10-22 12:01:07.832: I/System.out(638): s = {
10-22 12:01:08.278: D/AndroidRuntime(638): Shutting down VM
10-22 12:01:08.278: W/dalvikvm(638): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{banking_awareness.india.banking_gk/banking_awareness.india.banking_gk.QuestionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at banking_awareness.india.banking_gk.QuestionActivity.onCreate(QuestionActivity.java:312)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-22 12:01:08.312: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  ... 11 more
```

Here is GAActivity code

```
   private void loadQuestions() throws Exception
    {
        StringBuilder stringbuilder;
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ga)));
        stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String s = bReader.readLine();
        if (s == null)
        {

            try
            {
                Log.d(getClass().toString(), stringbuilder.toString());
                quesList = (new JSONObject(stringbuilder.toString())).getJSONArray("Questions");
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), (new StringBuilder("Num Questions ")).append(quesList.length()).toString());
            }
            catch (Exception exception2)
            {
                try
                {
                    bReader.close();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception exception3)
                {
                    Log.e("", exception3.getMessage().toString(), exception3.getCause());
                }
                return;
            }
            finally { }

            try
            {
                bReader.close();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception exception4)
            {
                Log.e("", exception4.getMessage().toString(), exception4.getCause());
            }

        }
        stringbuilder.append(s);

        try
        {
            bReader.close();
        }

        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            Log.e("", exception1.getMessage().toString(), exception1.getCause());
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's line QuestionActivity.java:312?

Comment: Your problem is in line 312

Comment: The line 312 is - selected = new int[GAActivity.getQuesList().length()];
             Arrays.fill(selected, -1);

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a value in selected ? try debugging the code and verify you are getting the selected variable value.

Comment: Actually when i click any button my Application is crashed. Not print anything on log cat only print 's = {'

Comment: Can you tell me where is the problem.

Comment: check my answer below, it might me the problem

Comment: Yah i change it on button code still getting problem is at line of - selected = new int[GAActivity.getQuesList().length()]; Arrays.fill(selected, -1);

Comment: @jassi : `getQuesList()` is *null*

Comment: @Kaushik :- But how ,  quesList like this code =  public static JSONArray getQuesList(){ eturn quesList; } and in another method is i have get json array in :- quesList = (new JSONObject(stringbuilder.toString())).getJSONArray("Questions");

Comment: see my edited answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine the error is in the following line in your `onCreate()` method:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.finish)).setOnClickListener(finishListener);
```

You are not defining a button that the `setOnClickListener` is registering to.

Seeing you have declared a Button called "finish", change you code to this:

```
finish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finish);
finish.setOnClickListener(finishListener);
```

One more thing:
As far as I can see your `GAActivity` is lacking the `getQuesList()` method, thus it is crashing.

I would imagine you look at [this](https://github.com/gitssk/quizfun/blob/master/src/ssk/quizfun/QuizFunActivity.java) code - notice at the bottom there is a `getQuesList()` method - that you don't have in your code.